# barplot: How to get the labels of y-axis outside the y-axis and the box, created with box()?

Tags: r, plot, latex, sweave, pdflatex

Bar plot looks in PDF file strange. Code:

```
pdf("fileName2.pdf", width=100, height=75)
par(resetPar())
par(mar=c(30, 150, 7, 7), lwd=2)
barplot(as.numeric(c(2, 4, 1, 6)), col = c("lightblue"), main="Bar plot",
        names.arg=c("This is \nbar 2...1","This is bar 2...2",
        "This is bar 2...3","This is bar 2...4"), , xpd=TRUE, las=1, lwd=3,
        horiz=TRUE, axes=TRUE, axis.lty=1, space=1, cex.axis=22, cex.names=22)
box(which="plot", lty="solid")#lty = '1373'
dev.off()
```

Question:
How to get the labels (1 to 15) of y-axis (here it is x-axis because horiz=TRUE) outside the box?

Comment: you can add them in a second time (not in the barplot call), then you can put them wherever you like

Comment: Your pdf is really large, as width and height are specified in inches. Also your cex parameters are large. Your code with smaller parameters plots everything fine: `pdf(fileName2.pdf",width = 12)
par(mar=c(4,10,4,1),cex=2, lwd=2)
barplot(as.numeric(c(2, 4, 1, 6)), col = c("lightblue"), main="Bar plot",
        names.arg=c("This is \nbar 2...1","This is bar 2...2",
                    "This is bar 2...3","This is bar 2...4"), las=1,horiz=TRUE, axes=TRUE)
box(which="plot", lty="solid")'
dev.off()`

Comment: @CathG: How can you add in that way after barplot?

Comment: see `?mtext` for example

Comment: Thanks, I will need `mtext` later for other figures!

Comment: @Jimbou Please, put your solution as answer! So that others can see it clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pdf is really large, as width and height are specified in inches. Also your cex parameters are large. Your code with smaller parameters plots everything fine:

```
pdf(fileName2.pdf",width = 12) par(mar=c(4,10,4,1),cex=2, lwd=2)      
barplot(as.numeric(c(2, 4, 1, 6)), col = c("lightblue"), main="Bar plot",
names.arg=c("This is \nbar 2...1","This is bar 2...2", 
"This is bar 2...3","This is bar 2...4"), las=1,horiz=TRUE, axes=TRUE) 
box(which="plot", lty="solid") 
dev.off()
```